# Python code needs to be tuned (ft. Fuzzywuzzy) -- How to make it faster

Tags: python, performance, optimization, text

I have programmed a python code and it works without errors, but It's extremely slow.
Can anyone help me to optimize my code, please?

```
import datatime
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

total_list = []
total_list_na = []

for idx, data in df_corr_adj.iterrows():
    st_date = (datetime.datetime.strptime(data.colct_dt_ttm, '%Y-%m-%d %H') + datetime.timedelta(hours = -120)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
    ed_date = (datetime.datetime.strptime(data.colct_dt_ttm, '%Y-%m-%d %H') + datetime.timedelta(hours = 24)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
    df_temp = df_naver[(df_naver["colct_dtm_adj"].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H')) >= st_date) & (df_naver["colct_dtm_adj"].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H')) <= ed_date)

    for idx2, data2 in df_temp.iterrows():
        if fuzz.token_set_ratio(data2.srchwrd, data.tot_noun) >= 80:
            total_list.append([data.youtube_id, data.colct_dt_ttm, data2.colct_dtm, 1, data2.item_no, data2.srchwrd])
        else :
            total_list_na.append([data.youtube_id, data.colct_dt_ttm, data2.colct_dtm, 1, data2.item_no, data2.srchwrd])
```

Thank you very much!!!

[df_corr_adj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H14ux.png)

[df_naver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jonn.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please point out where is the code getting slow the most. Also, what are you trying to do in the current code snippet so that folks can suggest appropriate ways to target efficiency ?

Comment: It gets slow when it starts iterrows() function. 

The purpose of the code is;
1. To compare data.tot_noun and data2.srchwrd and to select the rows which is over 80 using fuzzywuzzy package. 
2. To compare between data.colct_dt_ttm and its -120hours and +24hours of data2.colct_dtm_adj. For example, compare data.colct_dt_dtm(2020-12-24 10)’s tot_noun and data2.colct_dtm_adj(2020-12-24 10 + 24hrs ~ 2020-12-24 - 120hrs)’s srchwrd using iterrors.

Comment: It appears a O(nxm) not so good, anyway cannot work standalone, can you give us some kind of  df_corr_adj od mock data to test it?

Comment: I have attached the picture of the two datasets. Hope it helps..
It's my first time posting, so couldn't find where to upload the file :(

Comment: please make a runnable test,use mock data or fake data, but image is not a good way.

Comment: @이수현 you might want to try https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz for the string matching. It provides the same algorithms (`rapidfuzz.fuzz.token_set_ratio`), but it is a lot faster than FuzzyWuzzy.